# How do you make the root_url one level above the root/ and still keep the routes intact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a working application with proper routes.

The application then became shared with another application with a homepage below the two sites.

```
                     -- Root Homepage --
            /                                  \
           |                                   |
       Website 1                           Website 2
```

Now when I go to my page, the site loads. But the functioning does not.

**My Routes**

```
match '/generate_csv/(:id)', :to => "main#generate_csv", :via => :post, :as => "generate_csv"
resources :main
root :to => 'main#new'
```

Currently, my application is prepended by `rails/website_1`

How can I get my routes to line up again?

**UPDATE**

So this resolves the #create method, but I am still trying to get that first match route working..

```
scope "rails" do
  resources :main
  match 'main/generate_csv/(:id)', :to => "main#generate_csv", :via => :post, :as => "generate_csv"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by writing the routes twice. This can't be right:

```
  scope "rails" do
    resources :main
    match 'main/generate_csv/(:id)', :to => "main#generate_csv", :via => :post, :as => "generate_csv"
  end

  resources :main
  match 'main/generate_csv/(:id)', :to => "main#generate_csv", :via => :post, :as => "generate_csv"
  root :to => 'main#new'
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use a subdomain as an alternative when merging two separate sites by doing something like:

```
  constraints(:subdomain => /website1/) do
    match '/' => 'website2/dashboard#index'
  end
```

Otherwise, maybe try a scope:

```
scope module => "website1" do
  resources :main
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. Or at least my understanding is that subdomains are written as `sub.domain.com` where as this is index/website where as it was previously just /index where /index was website. The second item you offer..I just can't wrap my head around how that would work copying and pasting that into routes.rb

Comment: Yeah I meant using subdomains as an alternative to what you're trying to do. Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is to use a scope. Also, try posting your `rake routes` output.